# Why am I getting java.io.FileNotFoundException in this program?

Tags: java

Why am I getting java.io.FileNotFoundException in the following program?

```
import java.io.*;

class FisDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
/* Here we are accessing file abc.txt statically. i.e abc.txt must exist in current class directory */

        int  data;

        while(( data=fis.read())!=-1){
            System.out.println((char)data);
      // here we are casting, because return type of read() is int
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to post two completely unrelated questions in one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is abc.txt is not present(in the current directory).

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
```

Specify the full name of the file

```
    String fileFullName="/home/abc.txt";
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileFullName);
```

And yes is the answer for your second question.

Comment: try by giving the full path of the file.

Answer (score 2):

> FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");

Most likely you have bad `file path`.

So first you need to check where your file is located and then add right path.

Have also look at: [How to construct a file path in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-construct-a-file-path-in-java/) or [Construct file path](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Constructfilepath.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The program cannot find the abc.txt file. Maybe it is not present in your output / bin folder. It depends on your IDE if the file can be in src folder / resource folder or has to be copied to output folder after building the application.

Answer (score 0):

The file does not exist in current java file directory.Create it there and then try.